# Returning active user from IdentityServer4 when login to the MVC .netaspcore client

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller, identityserver4

I'm sure someone has asked this question or its something easy that i'm just struggling with.

I have going their the Identity Server docs and I've been able to setup as server, api, and MVC Client.

I'm able to login to the MVC Client using the Identity Server.

I'm trying to add currently login user and logout to a _loginPartial this should prove I can authorize view based on login as well. But I keep running into errors that UserManger is not doesn't have type registered.

any help or even a link to and example would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try the [samples](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/tree/master/samples/Quickstarts)? Please note that there are different implementations of storage. Certain samples use InMemory while other samples use EFCore. Take a look at `9_Combined_AspId_and_EFStorage`. This is a working sample that can be used as starting point.

Comment: Please note the UserManager is only available in the IdentityServer. The client has no access to the user store. So all the information you have is either in the claims (e.g. claim type name, given_name) or from the business store, e.g. an employee table where the `sub` claim links to an employee.

Comment: @RuardvanElburg Thanks I'll look into the Claims in more detail next.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the IdentityServer4 mvc client sample code, you could get current user from user claims.To display all the claims, you could use

```
@foreach (var claim in User.Claims)
{
    <dt>@claim.Type</dt>
    <dd>@claim.Value</dd>
}
```

Try to use below code in `_loginPartial.cshtml` to get `Name` claim of user

```
<ul class="navbar-nav">
    @if (User.FindFirst("Name").Value != null)
    {
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a> Hello @User.FindFirst("Name").Value !</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <form id="logoutForm" class="form-inline" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Logout"">
                <button id="logout" type="submit" class="nav-link btn btn-link text-dark">Logout</button>
            </form>
        </li>

    }
</ul>
```

Logout action:

```
public IActionResult Logout()
    {
        return SignOut("Cookies", "oidc");
    }
```